# Cut command to get second last word in each line | bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, cut

I have a bash script where I am using grep to get every line that contains a certain date:

```
(grep -h "$date" $1) > requests.txt
```

an example line being..

```
95.81.72.148 - - [22/Jan/2019:08:01:41 +0330] "GET /image/5384/productModel/100x100 HTTP/1.1" 200 2280 "https://link" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) IPADRESS Firefox/60.0" "-"
```

However I want to use piping and cut to somehow only store the IPADRESS of each line in the text file (the second to last word in the line)

How would I do this?

Comment: The second-to-last word in that line is `Firefox/60.0"`, the last word being `"-"`

Answer (score 3):

`awk` would be simpler, and it also subsumes the use of `grep`.

```
awk -v d="$date" '$0 ~ d { print $(NF - 2) }' "$1" > requests.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You ask how to do it with `cut`, and you get answers that tell you to use `awk` or `perl` :-). Of course you can do this with `cut` too:

```
rev |cut -d' ' -f3 | rev
```

This fails if the last two "words" contain spaces. But then, so do the `perl` and `awk` solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner, which prints field number 3 counting from the end (last field being `$F[-1]`):

```
perl -lane 'print $F[-3]'
```

Example:

```
echo '95.81.72.148 - - [22/Jan/2019:08:01:41 +0330] "GET /image/5384/productModel/100x100 HTTP/1.1" 200 2280 "https://link" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) IPADRESS Firefox/60.0" "-"' | \
  perl -lane 'print $F[-3]'
```

Output:

```
IPADRESS
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

---

BTW, `cut` is not the right tool for this task, because in `cut`, fields are numbered from the start. Meanwhile, in many scripting languages, such as Perl and awk, there is a method to split the line on whitespace, and count the fields from either the start *or* the end.